# Increment all integer elements by 1 in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I need  to increment the values for certain part of a ArrayList by a given number.

like `[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 1 ]`
lets say i need to increment last 3 elements by 2 
so that the result would be

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 3 3 3 ]
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any issue you have got?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and we will help you from there.

Comment: `how can i do this ?` Very easily, give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `arrayList` contains the `ArrayList<Integer>` instance:

```
int startFrom = arrayList.size() - 3;
int upTo = arrayList.size();
int incrBy = 2;

for (int i = startFrom; i < upTo && i < arrayList.size(); i += 1) {
    int oldValue = arrayList.get(i);
    int newValue = oldValue + incrBy;
    arrayList.set(i, newValue);
}
```

or, more compactly (i.e. inlining the variables `oldValue` and `newValue`):

```
for (int i = startFrom; i < upTo && i < arrayList.size(); i += 1) {
    arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(i) + incrBy);
}
```

Comment: Looping over all the list is actually taking a lot of time.

Comment: @user2590100: Is my code looping over the entire list? My Code is doing the exact same thing as the one in the answer you accepted, except it's using the correct `int` type not `String`. So you've basically accepted an answer that is broken.

Comment: I dont know how to accept two answers
Even your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the part that needed to be incremented in known *[from, to]* . You just loop on the ArrayList and add the number you wish: (remember that you can access the items in the ArrayList by index)

*`arr -  is ArrayList`*

*number* - is the number you wish to increment by

```
for (int i = from; i < to; i++){
       int item = arr.get(i);
       arr.set(i,item+number);
    }
```

- I assume here that `from` and `to` are valid indexes for the ArrayList but you should always check if they are within the array bounds

Comment: Looping over all the list is actually taking time

Comment: @MaD: `String item` and `item + number`? What?

Comment: @Erik Allik - Sorry about that. you are absolutely  correct.

Comment: ...there is unfortunately no type `Int` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint :* `ArrayList` provides indexed access to its members. You can easily loop over the required elements. For incrementing last `n` elements make use of a `for` loop and list's `size()`.

Comment: Looping over all the list is actually taking a lot of time.